# Snort IDS and malicious packet analys with WireShark

Tags: security, wireshark, snort, intrusion-detection

I have a .pcap packet which received to analysis malicious activity. Using 
Snort IDS and BarnYard2  detection I've captured 4 selectivities to  BASE ( Basic Analysis and Security Engine ) which shows as Portscan Traffic 100% .
four have 2 different IP address

```
Source : 10.214.116.188     Destination : 213.157.159.151
```

and

```
Source : 10.214.116.188     Destination : 186.160.247.133
```

[image]

Packet Opened with WireShark and first filter of

```
ip.dst==186.160.247.133
```

shows the below results 
[image]

and second filter

```
ip.addr==213.157.159.151
```

[image]

I need support to help understand what kind of attack this perform and how i can learn moreover about it.

packet : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-dY0nxt4UZXNGZ4UE5XbmZsY1U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I found 213.157.159.151 have RST/FIN flood type but still stuck with the SMTP requests.